# Why doesn't Typescript Intellisense show Object extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Consider this code to extend the Object type:

```
interface Object  
{
    doSomething() : void;
}

Object.prototype.doSomething = function ()
{
    //do something
}
```

With this in place, the following both compile:

```
(this as Object).doSomething();
this.doSomething();
```

BUT: when I'm typing the first line, Intellisense knows about the `doSomething` method and shows it in the auto-completion list. When I'm typing the second line, it does not.

I'm puzzled about this, because doesn't every variable derive from Object, and therefore why doesn't Visual Studio show the extra method in the method list?

## Update:

Even though the Intellisense doesn't offer the method, it **does** seem to recognize it when I've typed it manually:

[image]

What could explain that?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...because doesn't every variable derive from Object

No, for two reasons:

1. JavaScript (and TypeScript) has both objects and primitives. `this` can hold any value (in strict mode), and consequently can be a primitive:

```js
"use strict";
foo();
foo.call(42);

function foo() {
  console.log(typeof this);
}
```

[Here's that same code in the TypeScript playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0Afoo()%3B%0Afoo.call(42)%3B%0A%0Afunction%20foo()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(typeof%20this)%3B%0A%7D) In both cases (here and there), the above outputs:

```
undefined
number
```

...neither of which is derived from `Object`.

2. Not all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`:

```js
var obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(typeof obj.toString); // undefined
console.log("toString" in obj);   // false
```

If an object's prototype chain is rooted in an object that doesn't have a prototype at all (like `obj` above), it won't have the features of `Object.prototype`.

---

From your comment below:

> I thought even primitives like `number` inherit from `Object`. If `number` doesn't, how does `number.ToString()` work?

Primitives are primitives, which don't inherit from `Object`. But you're right that most of them *seem* to, because `number`, `string`, `boolean`, and `symbol` have object counterparts (`Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, and `Symbol`) which do derive from `Object`. But not all primitives do: `undefined` and `null` throw a `TypeError` if you try to treat them like objects. (Yes, [`null` is a primitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-primitive-value) even though `typeof null` is `"object"`.)

For the four of them that have object counterparts, when you use a primitive like an object like this:

```
var a = 42;
console.log(a.toString());
```

...an appropriate type of object is created and initialized from the primitive via the abstract [`ToObject` operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toobject) in the spec, and the resulting object's method is called; then unless that method returns that object reference (I don't think any built-in method does, but you can add one that does), the temporary object is immediately eligible for garbage collection. (Naturally, JavaScript engines optimize this process in common cases like `toString` and `valueOf`.)

You can tell the object is temporary by doing something like this:

```js
var a = 42;
console.log(a);         // 42
console.log(typeof a);  // "number"
a.foo = "bar";          // temp object created and released
console.log(a.foo);     // undefined, the object wasn't assigned back to `a`

var b = new Number(42);
console.log(b);         // (See below)
console.log(typeof b);  // "object"
b.foo = "bar";          // since `b` refers to an object, the property...
console.log(b.foo);     // ... is retained: "bar"
```

*(Re "see below": In the Stack Snippets console, you see `{}` there; in Chrome's real console, what you see depends on whether you have the console open: If you don't, opening it later will show you `42`; if you do, you'll see `▶ Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 42}` which you can expand with the ▶.)*

> Does `number` implement its own `toString` method, having nothing to do with `Object`?

[Yes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-number.prototype.tostring), but that doesn't really matter re your point about primitives and their odd relationship with `Object`.

So to round up:

- `this` may contain a primitive, and while some primitives can be treated like objects, not all can.
- `this` may contain an object reference for an object that doesn't derive from `Object` (which is to say, doesn't have `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain).

JavaScript is a hard language for IntelliSense. :-)

Comment: I thought even primitives like `number` inherit from `Object`. If `number` doesn't, how does `number.ToString()` work? Does `number` implement its **own** `toString` method, having nothing to do with `Object`?

Comment: Also, could you please have a look at the update to my post? Why would Visual Studio show that tooltip if it's not a safe thing to do on a variable that might not really be an `Object`?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: See updates to the answer. Re *"Why would Visual Studio show that tooltip if it's not a safe thing to do on a variable that might not really be an `Object`?"* JavaScript is a hard language for IntelliSense. I think when you start typing the name of something on `Object.prototype`, it defers to your understanding of the code. (I suspect if you started typing something that was only available on `String.prototype` or `Number.prototype`, it might also defer to you.)